# sudo not executing bashrc as expected

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, profile, bash-profile

Overall issue is when I log in, my prompt appears correctly formatted as per the /etc/bashrc but when I sudo to another user using bash, the prompt gets fubar'd.

Essential formatting in the /etc/bashrc

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
```

...and...

```
prompt_host=`/bin/hostname`
```

**Sequence:**

I log into my terminal as myuser.  My prompt is properly formatted as matching the /etc/bashrc above:

```
myuser@the.hostname.fully.qualified pwd :
```

Though the above implies my default shell program appears to be bash, I believe I'm using sh:

```
echo $SHELL     <---not very meaningful but I expect someone will ask me to run this
/bin/sh

ps -p `echo $$`
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 7105 pts/2    00:00:00 sh     <---which looks to be an interactive shell (no dash)

ps -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
72338     9321  9320  0 01:07 pts/3    00:00:00 -sh   <---or is it a login shell????

./filethatsnotthere.sh
-sh: ./filethatsnotthere.sh: No such file or directory
```

And last, but not least...

```
getent passwd myuser
myuser:x:72338:25000:My Name:/home/myuser:/bin/sh
```

Also, it's apparent that the /etc/profile is being sourced because:

```
echo $prompt_host
the.hostname.fully.qualified
```

So looks like sh and that the /etc/profile is being sourced.  BUT this confuses me...

```
 ls -l `which sh`
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 Jan 12  2018 /bin/sh -> bash
```

...sigh...But even if we go with the theory that I'm using sh, I then sudo to newuser using bash. newuser has a profile setup as newuser .bash_profile which sources newuser .bashrc which sources the /etc/bashrc.

But the prompt for newuser isn't working right and it's apparent that none of the newuser profile is run. It totally loses the hostname in the prompt

```
sudo -u newuser bash
newuser@ pwd         <---no hostname
```

I know NONE of the newuser profile is run because I put echo statements in them to confirm when they're run, and they don't display.  Even so, I've confirmed that newuser is truly running bash:

```
ps -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
newuser  11717 11715  0 03:47 pts/1    00:00:00 bash

ps -p `echo $$`
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
11717 pts/1    00:00:00 bash

./filethatsnotthere.sh
bash: ./filethatsnotthere.sh: No such file or directory
```

The /etc/profile is not being run (which makes sense since this is an interactive, not login, shell):

```
echo $prompt_host
<crickets....>
```

BUT - neither is newuser's startup files in the /home/newuser directory...So, if I'm using sudo to a user with command bash, why isn't that user's bash profile files being sourced?  Since it's an interactive shell, even though the /etc/profile is not directly being sourced I would still expect the newuser's files to be run.

Comment: `~/.bash_profile` is only sourced on login shells, which is not what `sudo -u newuser bash` creates. `/bin/sh` can be any posix compliant shell, including bash. On most systems it's a symlink to another shell. Bash does behave slightly differently when it's executed as /bin/sh. When it is, it's the same as launching it with `bash --posix`, which disables some shell features.

Comment: @jordanm so what files are sourced on interactive shells then.  Any?  Or only what's provided for the command (i.e. bash)?  Can I pass the bash command some parameters, like export?

Comment: Interactive non-login shells source `~/.bashrc`. See the "INVOCATION" section of the bash manpage for full details.

Comment: @jordanm That's what I thought, but as mentioned above, I put echo statements in the ~/.bashrc and they are not displayed (unless I manually source the file).

Comment: @jordanm thanks, figured it out with your help.

Comment: No problem. It may be helpful for others if you answer your own question with exact details on how you resolved it.

Comment: @jordanm - learning that it was an interactive shell led me past all the login shell expectations that I had.  I sort of hacked around it by adding an environment variable for the hostname to the .bashrc since that gets sourced by interactive shells.  Now the command prompt is complete.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` can be configured to set `$HOME` to match the new user when switching users, or not to. In your case, it appears it is set to not switch `$HOME`. That can be useful when you want to switch to user accounts that are dedicated to specific service applications, but still want to keep using *your* personal shell configuration and other settings.

And `~/.bashrc` is actually just a shorthand for `$HOME/.bashrc`.

So when you do `sudo -u newuser bash`, `sudo` switches the username to `newuser` but `$HOME` is still set to `/home/myuser`.

When `bash` attempts to execute `~/.bashrc`, it has a slight problem: as `newuser`, it might have no access to read `/home/myuser/.bashrc` unless you have specifically granted that access. If you haven't, that is probably why `.bashrc` is getting skipped. Because `$HOME` is still set to `/home/myuser`, there will be no attempt to execute `/home/newuser/.bashrc`.

If you want `sudo` to set `HOME=/home/newuser`, you can:

- use the `-H` option with the sudo command: `sudo -Hu newuser bash`
- or add `Defaults>newuser always_set_home` to your `sudoers` file to automatically set the home directory when switching to `newuser` only
- or add `Defaults:myuser always_set_home` to sudoers file to automatically set the home directory to match the new identity when `myuser` is running any `sudo` commands
- or add `Defaults always_set_home` to sudoers file to force this behavior for all `sudo` commands on the system. (Some Linux distributions have this enabled by default.)

---

If you don't especially want to switch the home directory when switching users, then you'll need to make sure the new user can read your personal shell startup files instead.

The minimal permissions you'd need to allow for `sudo -u newuser bash` to run `/home/myuser/.bashrc` are:

- a search permission to `/home/myuser`
- a read permission to `/home/myuser/.bashrc`

If there is no convenient user group that would be common to both `myuser` and `newuser`, and ACLs are not available (i.e. traditional Unix-style permissions only), this would be the traditional way to do it:

```
chmod 711 /home/myuser          # i.e. directory permissions drwx--x--x
chmod 644 /home/myuser/.bashrc  # i.e. file permissions      -rw-r--r--
```

If ACLs are available for the filesystem containing your home directory, you could do this instead to grant the minimal necessary access:

```
setfacl -m u:newuser:x /home/myuser
setfacl -m u:newuser:r /home/myuser/.bashrc
```

If the permissions of the home directory were initially `drwx------`, after this command the permissions to `/home/myuser` would look like `drwx--x---+`. To check the complete ACL, use `getfacl`:

```
$ getfacl /home/myuser
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: home/myuser
# owner: myuser
# group: myuser
user::rwx
user:newuser:--x
group::---
mask::--x
other::---
```